# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView not working properly

Tags: ios, react-native, tpkeyboardavoiding

I am trying to use the KeyboardAvoidingView with behavior="padding".

When I am trying to enter any text in TextInput, the TextInput field is not moving up. I have added a small view in the end which is moving up but the the view above it.

I have also with KeyboardAvoidingView height property with offset. It was working few components like 2 TextInputs. But when I add all the components the UI goes insane and behave jumbled up.

Any any idea whats happening over here?

Here the [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580) of tutorial which I have followed.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
            <Loader
                loading={this.state.isLoading} />
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                keyboardVerticalOffset={10}
                style={styles.mainContainer}
                behavior='padding' >
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <View style={[styles.centerContainer, { marginTop: 40 }]}>
                        <Image source={require('./../../Resources/logo.png')} />
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'gray', fontSize: 25 }}>AppName</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.loginMsg}> Login to your Account </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputFieldsContainer}>
                        <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30, margin: 5 }} source={require('./../../Resources/logo.png')} />
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder='Email'
                            returnKeyType='next'
                            keyboardType='email-address'
                            onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ userEmail: value })}
                            onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                            style={styles.inputFields} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputFieldsContainer}>
                        <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30, margin: 5, }} source={require('./../../Resources/logo.png')} />
                        <TextInput
                            returnKeyType='go'
                            secureTextEntry
                            placeholder='Password'
                            ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
                            onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ password: value })}
                            style={styles.inputFields} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Button
                            fontSize='8'
                            color='gray'
                            title='Remember Me'
                            onPress={() => {
                                console.log('Remember Me Clicked');
                            }} />
                        <Button
                            color='gray'
                            title='Forgot Password?'
                            onPress={() => {
                                console.log('Forgot Password Clicked');
                            }} />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.buttonLogin}
                        onPress={() => {
                                console.log('Login Clicked');
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white' }}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: 'gray', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 1 }}>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[styles.centerContainer, { marginBottom: 10 }]}>
                        <Text style={styles.loginMsg}>Don't have a Account</Text>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.buttonRegister}
                            onPress={() => navigate('Register')} >
                            <Text style={styles.buttonRegisterText}>REGISTER NOW</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: '#628499', }}>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'
},
mainContainer: {
    flex: 1, margin: 25,
    borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: 'gray',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
formContainer: {
    flex: 1, paddingLeft: 25, paddingRight: 25
},
centerContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 10,
},
loginMsg: {
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 20, color: 'gray'
},
inputFieldsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row', margin: 10,
    borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: 'gray',
},
inputFields: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5,
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
},
buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
buttonLogin: {
    alignItems: 'center', height: 40, marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 50, marginRight: 50, padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: 'gray'
},
buttonRegister: {
    alignItems: 'center', height: 40,
    marginLeft: 50, marginRight: 50
},
buttonRegisterText: {
    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'gray'
},
loading: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'
}, });
```

Comment: How about ScrollView instance of View on top

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11681

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but have you found the solution to this? facing this at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

I used KeyboardAvoidingView, it also doesn't work.
I found this solution, You can take the base code.

**Installation**

```
npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view --save
```

**Usage**

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
```

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  <View>
    <TextInput />
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

You can find it [here](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

Answer (score 2):

The way it worked for me was to use position as behavior and -70 as vertical offset. Any non negative integer was creating a huge unused space when the keyboard pops up.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={styles.container}
    behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'position' : 'height'}
    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? -70 : 70}
    enabled>
     <ScrollView>
       ...
     </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={styles.mainContainer}
  behavior="padding"
  enabled
>
  <View>.......................</View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

'Enabled or disabled KeyboardAvoidingView' should be add.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind  is always your top Parent with flex:1 then the child is   then you text input container

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{  flex: 1 }}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "position" : null} enabled>
          <ScrollView>
            <View>
              <View >
                <Text maxFontSizeMultiplier={1.5} >
                  Sign in to your account{" "}
                </Text>
                 <View
                    behavior="padding"
                    enabled
                  >
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder="Email address"
                      placeholderTextColor={Colors.grey}
                      style={styles.textInput}
                      onChangeText={(e) => setEmail(e.trim())}
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      returnKeyType={"done"}
                    />
                  </View>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

 // 2nd Solutions use this package 

npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view --save

import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'

<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  <View>
    <TextInput />
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```